# Drupal Google Maps clustering of nodes.

Tags: 8, nodes, google-maps

I am trying to find a way I can cluster nodes on a Google Map from a custom entity according to particular regions in a country. I have been using the [Geocoder](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder) module to geocode addresses but I now want to group these addresses into regional clusters. I need a way I can implement Google Map clustering in Drupal 8.

If there is a way to do it programtically please do not hesitate to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to cluster your map pins/node results, you'll need to write your own javascript function to call the Google Maps Clustering Library/initialize the map (since as of Feb 23, 2018, the GMap module has yet to be fully ported/available for D8).

Based on [Google's Marker Clustering Documentation/Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering), I'd recommend creating a custom module that includes:

1. The [Google Maps Marker Clusterer js library](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer).
2. Setting up a json endpoint/route for the location nodes/entities
3. Custom module javascript that loads the nodes from the endpoint above and parses them (their latitude & longitude data) for the locations array in the init_map function.

***Worth noting:***
The Google Maps clustering library is grid-based, dividing the map into squares of a certain size.

If you want regions bounded by state/provincial borders, this library won't satisfy the zoomed out map with multiple regions; you'll need something more custom. In such a case, you can:

1. add a taxonomy for the regions (with a custom set of geocoordinates for the center or political capital of each region)
2. load a custom high level map with the regions defined/outlined with svg polygon paths and displaying custom cluster pins
3. on each specific regional map utilize the grid-based clustering library

Comment: I am still figuring out how am going to implement this solution but it has been very helpful so i will mark it as the correct answer.